# Magento Certification - multi-answer multiple choice questions

Tags: magento-1, certification

For those of you that have taken the test or know about it - I notice there are questions that require you to choose 4 correct answers out of 6. If I get 3 right and 1 wrong, am I given any marks at all?

Comment: No. There are two options: Answer correct or wrong. 3 out of 4 is wrong :)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt might be worth posting as an answer ;-)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt please post it as an answer.

Comment: I thought it will be converted to a comment, so I just put a comment here :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. There are two options: Answer correct or wrong. 3 out of 4 is wrong :)

Answer (score -1):

No, 3 out of 4 is still wrong. You have to answer totally right.

I am from Magestore and we have developed a FREE Magento Test Tool with +200 Magento questions. 
Here is the link: http://bit.ly/1OUri5R

I am not spamming. I just want to share with you the information!

Hope it help!